# Comparison of parsing data in Ruby using Nokogiri and Python using lxml and xpath

Tags: python, ruby, xpath, nokogiri, lxml

I am trying to convert Ruby syntax into its Python equivalent:

Here is the Ruby code:

```
collection_action :updateBackPlayers, :method => :get do

url="http://fantasyfootball.telegraph.co.uk/premierleague/select-team"
website = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

elements=website.xpath('//*[@id="list-GK"]/table/tr')

arr = []
elements.each do |row|
  x=row.xpath('td')
  name = x[0].text
  club = x[1].text
  @player=Player.find_by_name_and_club(name,club)
  arr=x[7].text.split("|")
  score=arr[1].split("/")   
  cards=arr[3].split("/") 
  clean_sheets = arr[2].split("/")
  goals=arr[4]

  weekly_points = arr[0].to_i - (@player.points || 0)

  @player.update_attributes(:weekly_points => weekly_points, :points => arr[0].to_i, :value=>x[2].text.to_f, :games=>score[0].to_i, :part_appearances=>score[1], :goals=>goals.to_i  )
  @player.update_attributes(:yellows=>cards[0], :reds=>cards[1], :clean_sheets=> clean_sheets[0], :part_clean_sheets=>clean_sheets[1]  )
  #@player.penalties_saved = arr[2]     
end
```

This is of-course using Nokogiri, but I would like to do the same using lxml and XPath and then save this information in a Django model using SQLite3.

Here is the Python code.

```
 from lxml.html import parser
 url = "http://fantasyfootball.telegraph.co.uk/premierleague/select-team"
 website = parse(url)

 elements = website.xpath('//div[@id="list-GK"]//table/tr')

 for row in elements:
     x = row.xpath('td')
       for z in x:
         name = z[1].text
         club = z[2].text
```

But this doesn´t work and I get an out of limit error. I think the problem lies in the `elements.each do |row|` isn´t completely the same as `for row in elements:` in Python.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But if i do:

```
from lxml.html import parse
from fanaments.models import Player

url="http://fantasyfootball.telegraph.co.uk/premierleague/select-team"
page = parse(url)


elements = page.xpath('//div[@id="list-GK"]//table/tr')


for row in elements:
   x = row.xpath('td')
   for z in x:
        print z.text
```

I get the following:

```
None
Hart, J
MCY
4.0
20
11.6%
None
Hart, Joe
MCY|£4.0m|5|0||20|0|0|0|4|0|0|3|0|0||||unknown|
MCY|£4.0m|39|0||140|1|0|0||0||18|0|1|||||
None
de Gea, D
MUN
3.9
15
6.4%
None
de Gea, David
MUN|£3.9m|5|0||15|0|0|0|6|0|0|2|0|0||||unknown|
MUN|£3.9m|33|0||99|0|0|0||0||11|0|0|||||
```

How can I manage to save the name as name and so forth?? Please help I have been stuck on this too long :)

Comment: Why are you using `name = x[1].text` and `club = x[2].text`? Python list indexes (indices?) also start with 0. And you wrote `for z in x:` but don't use `z`. Did you mean `for z in row.xpath('td'): name = z[0].text; club = z[1].text`?

Comment: Yes I meant name = z[0].text sorry for that? How can I do this properly? I just want to save the name, the club, the points ect.. But I don´t really get how I can do it? Because the table I am scraping repeats itself again and again and the first td element is always the name and the second one the club and soforth. I just wan´t to get the data - save it to my model.